# Site Graduated!

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable design feedback.

We have also themed the [twitter account](https://twitter.com/stackraspi) and newsletter template for this site.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug".

You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators - there is some backlog here as the elections for some of the first-wave sites have also had to be delayed. Elections for you and the other sites in this wave will start being scheduled in December.

Also, you will soon be able to select your own community ads. We're very close to the new year and the new ad cycle, and we have some exciting changes planned for these as well. These, too, will begin in December or early January so that you may enjoy the new changes.

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Oh! And btw. we have also updated your [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery) theme!

Comment: \O/ Now might be a good time for us to develop and propose community ads for other sites too (something I've previously neglected) -- but that's a whole other meta question (I'll amend this comment sometime in the next day or so).

Comment: Woo! I haven't been active on here in a while simply because of time constraints and school and whatnot, but awesomesauce! Nice job RPi.SE!

Comment: Great news, and thanks to the moderators for all the hard work they have put in behind the scenes.

Comment: Again congratulations to all of the community members that have made this milestone possible.

Comment: Wonderful! And the new theme is pretty cool!

Comment: Awesome !! Thrilled to see new design this morning. :) \m/

Comment: At last! Been trying my best to sort out stale answers and get people to accept any oldies. Thanks to everyone above who also provide excellent content and kept thing going. Great news that allot more people are now visiting this site and its officially, official !!  :)

Comment: I literally found this out from A51 where I noticed we had a logo now! Will there be swag?

Comment: Everything looks amazing. Well done! :)

Comment: Nice, but I still couldn't find the graduation diploma. Anyone else noticed this?

Answer (score 9):

Just a couple of mistakes on the chat pages:

1. The footer is still using the old beta font and colours, and has the beta tag.

[image: Footer, bottom right hand corner]

2. Some of the buttons up the top right hand corner are still using the old logo.

[image: Old logos on buttons]

(sorry about my bad [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/285368))

Comment: +1 for freehand circles ^^

Comment: Should be fixed now after a reload, can you confirm?

Comment: @balpha Yep, fixed! Looking great! Also, can you please pass our thanks onto the whole SE team, we are very appreciative for all your hard work.

Comment: Will do, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Just another logo mistake... This time on the iOS app

[image: Old Beta logo on menu and in profile]

I don't have the Android app, if someone can check it that would be great.

Comment: Appears to be fixed

Comment: yes, it should be fixed now. thanks for reporting!